# How to generate a mocked object that is created within the class being tested?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I have a testing class that instantiates a class that I wish to be mocked.  Is this possible within the gmock framework?  From what I read, it seems that the mocked object has to be created and passed to the object being tested and that is not what I want.

I've got it so that I can inject my mocked class into the source, but I'm stuck as to how to get it to generate the appropriate object.

Comment: Can you explain the reason behind the question? I try to understand why would you want to mock the return object... Basically the answer is simple you can't mock the object, but we all here to learn and help each other....

Comment: If I want to mock a class, then I would like my class to be used, even if it is being generated within the class that I am testing.  Let's say that it's a transient object, generated, used, and destroyed.  Sometimes within the same function, sometimes not.  Sometimes released exterior to the class, sometimes not.

Comment: you should mock the object only if it doing a complex operation/affect on external resources and etc... If your case is match one of the cases I mentioned then your probably violate `SRP`(if so, you should refactor the code). If the object is a `PoD` object then you shouldn't mock it at all, instead you can verify the state of the object at the end of the method...

Comment: @OldFox, I'm just developing the framework for adding testing to a legacy application. My primary concern is to be able to replace class definitions in place since this is a legacy app that didn't need to virtualize the dependant class interface. Switching this at this late stage (20+ years later) would be too much time required. Whether it should be done or not is secondary to it not working due to type inconsistency. However, thanks for the info. I shall look into the info you stated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to put the `EXPECT_CALL()` into the constructor, using `*this` as the first parameter.  Of course, this only works if you expect it to be the same all the time.

This will get more complex if the expected behaviour is going to vary from instance to instance, unless each instance uses a different constructor.

If using the same constructor, then your mocked class could use a static counter which could change what is expected depending on the instance count.